# How to save Recorded VideoFile in CWAC Camera

Tags: android, cwac-camera

As I find there is a method for PictureTransaction to save images in Cwac. How do we go about saving the Video Recorded by cwac camera?

Comment: The CWAC-Camera library has been discontinued. Beyond that, [the documentation covers how to control the file where `MediaRecorder` will write the video](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-camera/blob/master/README-original.markdown#controlling-the-names-and-locations-of-output-files).

Comment: @CommonsWare thanks for your prompt reply I have created my MyHost which extends Camera Host. So I have pass save Image to save images which is working fine but in case of videos which method should i pass ?